# how to aggregate the rows as count & only show 1 row as answer?

Tags: sql

(Q: count the #customers with firstname Mary who purchased more than 10 items)

```
SELECT x.first_name, COUNT(y.customer_id) AS ordercount
FROM [customers] x
JOIN orders y ON x.customer_id = y.customer_id
WHERE x.first_name = 'Mary'
GROUP BY x.first_name
HAVING COUNT(y.customer_id)>10
ORDER BY x.first_name ASC;
```

Comment: This question is expecting a single number, being the number of Marys - why are you selecting the name (it's going to be Mary) and what does `city` or `country` have to do with the question? Tip - learn to use *meaningful* aliases.

Comment: because I want to get the aggregate amount for all Mary who purchased more than 10 items from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT s.first_name, COUNT(s.customer_id) AS customercount
FROM (
    SELECT c.*
    FROM [customers] c
    JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
    WHERE c.first_name = 'Mary'
    GROUP BY c.customer_id
    HAVING COUNT(o.order_id)>10
    ) s
GROUP BY s.first_name
```

You have to find all of the customers with more than 10 purchases *first* (in the subquery) and then you can count how many there are (in the outer query).